# What does happen with the minus one in the quadratic equation?

Tags: polynomials

1) Initial expression: -n^2+5n+24

2) Factoring out negative one: -1(n^2-5n-24)

3) Factorized form: -1(n-8)(n-8)

In the next step, what does happen with with the minus one if I am to solve for n?

Also, if in the second step -1 corresponds to the whole expression inside the parantheses, why do we factor out -1 just in front of the first (n-8)?

Comment: Your factorization is wrong!

Comment: $(n-8)(n-8)=n^2-16n+64$ nothing like your polynomial

Comment: Strictly speaking there is nothing to *solve* in $-(n-8)(n-8)$. Assuming we want to solve $-(n-8)(n-8)=0$, the solutions are the same as the solutions of $(n-8)(n-8)=0$, since a number equals zero iff its opposite equals zero. Anyway, $$-n^2+5n+24 = -(n+3)(n-8).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to "solve" for a variable, say $n$, you have to set the quadratic equal to $0$ to find its roots.

$$-n^2+5n+24=0$$

Here, you can multiply both sides by $-1$:

$$-1\times(-n^2+5n+24)=-1\times(0)$$

$$n^2-5n-24=0$$

Which finally results in:

$$(n-8)(n+3)=0$$